# Best way to store profile images with Android, App engine + datastore

Tags: android, google-app-engine, google-cloud-storage

i am using Android with google app engine endpoints backend storing data with datastore.
Now i want to add and store user images. What is the best way to integrate Google cloud storage:

1. create an new endpoint with blobs in the api and call cloud storage from the endpoint?
   Android -->--> App Engine Endpoint --> Google Cloud Storage
   Google Cloud Storage --> App Engine Endpoint -->  -->Android
2. Directly call Google cloud storage from Android device without endpoint?
   Android --> --> Google Cloud Storage
3. Better alternative?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Your option 1 would only work if you the image was under 1MB because that is the maximum size in datastore for a base64 encoded string (which is what you would pass to your endpoint method)

Your option 2 I would not recommend because then you would be storing service account keys to GCS straight in the client, and that would not be secure (unless you didn't care).

Option 3 is what I did:

I have an Endpoints method that generates a [signed url](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control#Signed-URLs) (or you can use [resumable url](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/json_api/v1/how-tos/upload#resumable)). Signed urls are timed and expire. The object name and bucket are specified in the signed url. I call my endpoints method in Android to get the signed url and use an `HttpURLConnection` to upload the image to GCS.

Like me, you will probably want a callback method when your object uploads to GCS. This is a bit more complicated but you will need to create a servlet in your Endpoints project and handle accordingly. The documentation is very helpful for [Object Change Notification](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/object-change-notification#_Reliable_Delivery).

Comment: With Option 1 i did not want to store it in datastore. I thought it would be possible to store the binary image data from the endpoint directly in the cloud storage. The Cient (Android) calls an endpoint of my application to upload the data to server. Then the endpoint upload the data to GCS bucket.

Comment: To your option 3:
how do you transfer the data from your client to your server? WIth the signed URL from client or through the endpoint?

Image Profiles should be readable from every user that is a friend of the uploader. Is signed URLs the way to go for that case?

Comment: My scenario is as follows:
Each user of the app has an account. The account data is stored in datastore. The user now should have the possibility to upload an profile image. The image should be stored on GCS. 
The upload should go through endpoint because of authentication.
For the download a url should be availbale, so the images must not be downloaded through an endpoint. The url should be accessible forever for each user that is connected to the uploader in my app.

Comment: is there a restriction of 1 MB for binary parameteres in an endpoint method?
Using serialized objects as parameter in a POST request should work like this:



public class Image implements Serializable {
 private byte[] data;

 public Image() {
  super();
 }

 public byte[] getData() {
  return data;
 }
 public void setData(byte[] data) {
  this.data = data;
 }
}


mehtod:

@ApiMethod(name = "endpoint.uploadImage", httpMethod = HttpMethod.POST )
public boolean uploadImage(User user, Image image)  
throws OAuthRequestException {
...
}

Comment: @SmilingM You can't store the binary image data from endpoint directly to cloud storage. Cloud Endpoint methods can't take binary data as parameters.

Comment: @SmilingM You use `HttpURLConnection` to transfer data from client to (GCM) server. Google how to use it in android - there are many examples. Image profiles can be read by other users with signed URLs. Your endpoint method can create signed URLs for reading and writing. Again, see the docs.

Comment: @SmilingM You are asking a mouthful but basically to answer your last question "The url should be accessible forever for each user that is connected to the uploader in my app." - You really need to read the docs or take an online course on Google Cloud Storage. That will answer all of your questions and how it works - it is simply too much to type here but in my answer I gave you a general template to follow as you learn more about GCS. Best of luck sir!

Comment: Hi MicroR, 
can you share some sample code how you upload your data with the signed URL? In my test I always get 503 error using the following code:
uploadObject(String uploadUrl, byte[] d) {URL url = new URL(uploadUrl); HttpsURLConnection connection= HttpsURLConnection) url.openConnection();
connection.setDoOutput(true);
connection.setRequestMethod("PUT");
OutputStream out = new BufferedOutputStream(connection.getOutputStream());
out.write(d); out.close(); 
int res = connection.getResponseCode();
return res;}

Comment: Just wanted to chime in here to say that the documentation on the [Cloud Platform](https://cloud.google.com/docs/) is a great place to start to find out about what possibilities are out there for a solution, and you can also find tons of examples on the [Cloud Platform github account](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform).